# Remove annotation for podcast episodes?

Tags: support

There are annotations in a black banner at the top of the site every once in a while. I'd like to see annotations when something goes on, but right now it's mostly used to announce new podcast episodes, which is something I do not care at all about. Blocking the whole banner presumably means I won't see notifications about anything at all, which is not what I want.
Could I avoid just the podcast annotations somehow?

Comment: Did you try my userscript? It's linked in a comment on the duplicate.